# 自分も手会う Translation

Tags: translation

I need to translate the following.

```
安田さんは、
結婚してから
家内にばかり料理をさせないで、
自分も手会うようにしている
そうです
```

So far I have the following.

```
Yasuda-san
after getting married
without letting anyone but his wife cook?
he was trying to ... also meet a hand by himself?
I heard.
```

Obviously, I'm not getting that 4th line. And the 3rd line I am not sure about. I know the following.

- 自分 = one's self
- 手 = hand
- 会う = to meet

Maybe 手会うis a verb I am unfamiliar with? I can't seem to find it online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the context, the correct word should be 「[手伝]{てつだ}う」.  「手会う」 makes no sense.

「[自分]{じぶん}も手伝うようにしている。」 = "He has been trying to help (her cook)."

「[自分]{じぶん}」 refers to the husband here (and it is a key word in Japanese, in which pronouns are rarely used).

Your 3rd line looks off as well.  It literally means "Without letting only his wife do the cooking".  More naturally, "without letting his wife do all the cooking", perhaps?  I dunno.  Don't trust my English.

Comment: Ah. Maybe that kanji was a typo in the handout. Thanks for the help. I think I understand.

Comment: Perhaps: Yasuda-san / Since he got married, /[by] not letting his wife do all the cooking / has been trying to help by lending a hand.
=> Since he got married, Yasuda-san has been trying to help by lending a hand and not letting his wife do all the cooking.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "without MAKING his wife do all the cooking"?